# Can i detach Sharepoint 2007 Databases from a SQL Server 2008R2 and attach on SQL Server 2014 without migrate Sharepoint?

Tags: migration, sharepont, sql-server-2014

I would like to known if i can detach Sharepoint 2007 Databases from SQL Server 2008R2 (Windows Server 2008R2)  and attach on SQL Server 2014 (Windows Server 2012R2) without migrate Sharepoint?

Assuming it's possible, here's what I would do:

- Stop Sharepoint Services and IIS on my WFEs
- Detach the Sharepoint DBs from SQL SERVER 2008R2
- Attach all Sharepoint DBs on SQL Server 2014
- Fire up all the Sharepoint Services and IIS again

Anyone have any recommendations?

Tks,
Kenny

Answer (score 0):

I guess SharePoint 2007 does not support SQL server 2012 or later version, so you cannot migrate on SQL server 2014.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/cc262485(v=office.12)

As per above document:

> Office SharePoint Server 2007 does not support SQL Server 2012 or
>   later versions of SQL Server.